# Why PyTorch creates another data repro TorchData

Tags: pytorch, dataset, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader, data-pipeline

Why PyTorch creates another repro called `TorchData` for similar/new `Dataset` and `DataLoader` instead of adding them in the existing PyTorch repro? What's the difference of `Dataset` and `Datapipe`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TorchData` is a library of common modular data loading primitives for easily constructing flexible and performant data pipelines.

It aims to provide composable `Iterable-style` and `Map-style` building blocks called `DataPipes` that work well out of the box with the PyTorch's DataLoader. It contains functionality to reproduce many different datasets in TorchVision and TorchText, namely including loading, parsing, caching, and several other utilities (e.g. hash checking).

`DataPipe` is simply a renaming and repurposing of the PyTorch Dataset for composed usage. A DataPipe takes in some access function over Python data structures, `__iter__` for `IterDataPipes` and `__getitem__` for MapDataPipes, and returns a new access function with a slight transformation applied.